# Possible to Create a pipeline run of Synapse from Power Automate?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, power-automate

I have tested that it is possible to create Power Apps button, which calls Power Automate flow, which create Pipeline run for Azure Data Factory.

However I cannot find similar functionality for calling Synapse Integrate pipeline.

Synapse is not supported in Power Automate? What is workaround?

Comment: I don't use Power Apps, but I imagine you could either use an Azure Function or HTTP request to call the API directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with **@Joel Cochran** and **AFAIK**, there is no Connector to connect Synapse Pipelines.

So, call the Synapse Pipeline REST API via http POST.

Here I have used logic app to call the Pipeline. To call from logic app, **enable the managed identity of logic app** and add it in the **Synapse Access control**.

[image]

In the flow, use the following URI in http POST action.

```
https://<Synapse_workspace_name>.dev.azuresynapse.net/pipelines/<Pipeline_name>/createRun?api-version=2020-12-01
```

For Authentication, give system managed identity.

[image]

Save it and call the http trigger URI from postman or anyone.

[image]

**Pipeline run:**

[image]

You can do the same from Power automate as well. In this Use the same http POST action and give the above REST API as URI.

You can use the authentication as per your requirement.
Here, I have used **Active Directory OAuth** for authentication. I have created a service principal and added it in **Synapse Access control**.

Then give the service principal credentials like tenant id, client id and secret values in the flow.

[image]

You can do like above or you can call the logic app from Power Automate to achieve your requirement.