# How to perform CDC for synapse table?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-synapse-analytics

I have a Table in Azure Synapse. Requirement is : Whenever changes happens to a table , i need to capture those changes and reflect it in a another table in another database of synapse. So Simply i wanted to implement CDC for Synapse table WRT Inserts /Updates /Deletes.

Pls let me know your ideas. Thanks

Comment: have you tried any approach and facing error?

Comment: No i havent tried anything, Looking for inputs

Answer (score 0):

Synapse Dataflows gives the option of CDC, but currently as per [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/concepts-change-data-capture#auto-incremental-extraction-in-mapping-data-flow), it is not suported for Synapse tables.

You can raise a feature request for that [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/9b9ba8e4-0825-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f07b8).

As a workaround, you can try the below approach, but this approach requires a column for the incremental load and a logic app which triggers the synapse pipeline whenever there is any modification in the table..

Go to Synapse Dataflow, give synapse table as source dataset and enable the **Incremental column** and give the column.

[image]

Give your target table in sink. In synapse pipeline, take a dataflow activity and give the above dataflow with following configurations.

[image]

Publish this pipeline and create a logic app and take **When an item is modified (V2)** trigger of SQL server. Create connection with Synapse database configurations and give the table.

[image]

Now, use HTTP post as action to trigger the Synapse pipeline. Follow this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76200692/possible-to-create-a-pipeline-run-of-synapse-from-power-automate/76206760#76206760) to do that.

On every change of the table, the above logic app will trigger the synapse pipeline. The pipeline's dataflow will transform the data incrementally to the required target table.

Comment: Hey , Thanks for your insights. For this flow deletes are not being captured. Do you have any say over this? Inserts and updates are being captured but not deletes.

Comment: The above will not work for delete. If you want it for delete, you can try SQL server connector in logic app. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connectors/built-in/reference/sql/#triggers) for more understanding about it.

Comment: That Incremental column workaround is not able to capture deletes. It captures only inserts and updates. Trigger part is not a issue since we will schedule it daily once.

Comment: Ok, I think you can try alter row transformation before the sink in dataflow. The above approach won't give required result for delete. But alter row had Insert, Update, Upsert and Delete as well. In the dataflow, add this transformation before the sink. Go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/connectors/built-in/reference/sql/#triggers). I didn't tried it but I think it will work.